# How to remove a div with an href link?

Tags: html, href

I want to remove `div` by clicking on the link.
I have tested:

```js
function mafunction() {
  jQuery('.idf').on('click').closest('.truc').remove();
}
```

```html
<div class=" truc">
  <a class="idf" href="javascript: mafunction();">delete</a> 
</div>
```

I don't understand why this is not working?

Comment: I have translated your title to English because you must use English here and converted your code to snippet so there are no need to use jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o4LuL3gt/)

Just use the regular document ready for your event binding

```
$(function() {
    $('.idf').on('click', function(event) {
       $(this).closest('.truc').remove();
       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Moving that binding into the href means it would only get bound on click, so the event would fire the following click (maybe).

Comment: Thank's for repply, i want use the href because may div truc is add if user click on button

Comment: @user3575562 - It's ok jQuery.on uses delegated event binding, you can add new divs/hrefs and it will automatically bind them.

Comment: If i add the code in my footer doesn't work ! I have add the code after div added and work fine. Thank's Jeff !!!